# Displaying sub-categories using Timber

Tags: php, wordpress, children, timber, wp-list-categories

I'm showing the top-level categories using the following:

```
$context['categories'] = Timber::get_terms('category');
$categories = get_categories( array(
'hide_empty' => '0',
'exclude'    => '1',
'orderby'    => 'id',
'order'      => 'ASC'
) );
$context['categories'] = $categories;

{% for cat in categories %}
  <li {% if term.slug == cat.slug %}class="active"{% endif %}><a href="{{blog.link}}category/{{cat.slug}}">{{cat.name}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

But I need to display the sub-categories in a drop-down (bootstrap 4). But I'm not sure how to go about accessing them? I'm thinking they are already available  with something like `cat.child`?

Comment: I got exactly the same problem, is there  any chance that you've solved it yet?

Comment: I haven't, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is way easier than i thought it was,
you(and me) were doing this completely the wrong way.
first you have to go to your themes, and select menu's.
then you have to make shore all your sub-categories are a child of the category you want them to have.

once you've done that, you can just put in the following code and your drop-down menu will work.

```
{% for item in menu.get_items %}
                <li class="nav-item {{ item.classes | join(' ') }}">
                    {% if item.get_children %}

                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" id='dropdownMenuButton' data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expended="false" >
                            {{ item.title }}
                        </button>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby='dropdownMenuButton'>
                            {% for child in item.get_children %}
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{child.link}}">{{child.title}}</a>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    {% else %}
                    <a href="{{ item.link }}" title="{{ item.title }}" class="nav-link">{{ item.title }}</a>
                    {% endif %}

                </li>
{% endfor %}
```

for me this worked at least